# Crystal report in MVC in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am trying to do Generate a Crystal Report in My MVC application. My application is Developed in Visual Studio 2013. I don't know Because of that of what I am not able to generate the Crystal Report in My MVC application. While I am doing

`Add ->New Item-> Reporting`

then I am not able to get the Crustal report Template for Generating reports.
I have also Installed `CRforVS_13.exe`
from `http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_7.exe`

But still I am not able to get that template for generating New Crystal Report.
 Please help me on this that what is the Problem.

Comment: take a look to this article http://kbochevski.blogspot.in/2010/01/aspnet-mvc-and-crystal-reports.html, If you are using sql server thnk of using RDLC that are better integrated in MVC

Comment: I would recommend if it all possible NOT to use CR with VS 2013, personally it has given me nothing but problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the latest Service Pack ? It had fixes to some bugs.

you can download it from here: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

Also some developers complained about CR not working when installing the x64 bit version and instead use the 32bit version.